# Anyone know how to get historical stock data for free in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, api, stocks

I'm looking for an API that can be accessed via C# implementation where I can get access to free stock market historical information (index and individual companies).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stock Trading script/language for .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222357/stock-trading-script-language-for-net)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I get free real-time stock data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/281263/where-can-i-get-free-real-time-stock-data)

Comment: The easiest way is to use the undocumented Yahoo historical stock functions. I have an example here: http://jarloo.com/code/api-code/get-historical-stock-data/

Comment: Question shows no sign of prior research.  What have you tried?  What have you researched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a couple of [C# examples on my blog](http://mlai-lirik.blogspot.com/search/label/historical%20data) for getting historical data from Yahoo. It's really simple...

### Update

Regarding my example... I'm not saving the data to anything, I'm just printing in the console. You'd have to save the data in whatever format or data structure is most reasonable for you.

```
// A dictionary with tags where the key is the tag
// and the value is the description of the tag
private Dictionary<string, string> _tags = new Dictionary<string, string>();

private void DownloadData(String symbol)
{
    string url = String.Format(
        "http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s={0}&f=", symbol);

    //Get page showing the table with the chosen indices
    HttpWebRequest request = null;
    DFDataSet ds = new DFDataSet();
    Random rand = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
    try
    {
        while (_running)
        {
            foreach (String key in _tags.Keys)
            {
                lock (_sync)
                {
                    request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.CreateDefault(
                        new Uri(url + key));
                    request.Timeout = 30000;

                    using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                    using (StreamReader input = new StreamReader(
                        response.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} {1} = {2}",
                            symbol, _tags[key], input.ReadLine());
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.Name + " running.");
            Thread.Sleep(60*1000); // 60 seconds
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
    }
}
```

Note that you can request multiple tags in the same csv file, instead of one tag at a time... to do that, just string all the tags of interest together and add them to the URL just like you add a single tag. The values for the tags will be comma separated.

### Update 2.0

Here is how you can get end of day (EOD) historical data from yahoo:

```
void DownloadDataFromWeb(string symbol)
{
    DateTime startDate = DateTime.Parse("1900-01-01");

    string baseURL = "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?";
    string queryText = BuildHistoricalDataRequest(symbol, startDate, DateTime.Today);
    string url = string.Format("{0}{1}", baseURL, queryText);

    //Get page showing the table with the chosen indices
    HttpWebRequest request = null;
    HttpWebResponse response = null;
    StreamReader stReader = null;

    //csv content
    string docText = string.Empty;
    string csvLine = null;
    try
    {
        request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.CreateDefault(new Uri(url));
        request.Timeout = 300000;

        response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        stReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), true);

        stReader.ReadLine();//skip the first (header row)
        while ((csvLine = stReader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string[] sa = csvLine.Split(new char[] { ',' });

            DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(sa[0].Trim('"'));
            Double open =  double.Parse(sa[1]);
            Double high = double.Parse(sa[2]);
            Double low = double.Parse(sa[3]);
            Double close = double.Parse(sa[4]);
            Double volume = double.Parse(sa[5]);
            Double adjClose = double.Parse(sa[6]);
            // Process the data (e.g. insert into DB)
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
}

string BuildHistoricalDataRequest(string symbol, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    // We're subtracting 1 from the month because yahoo
    // counts the months from 0 to 11 not from 1 to 12.
    StringBuilder request = new StringBuilder();
    request.AppendFormat("s={0}", symbol);
    request.AppendFormat("&a={0}", startDate.Month-1);
    request.AppendFormat("&b={0}", startDate.Day);
    request.AppendFormat("&c={0}", startDate.Year);
    request.AppendFormat("&d={0}", endDate.Month-1);
    request.AppendFormat("&e={0}", endDate.Day);
    request.AppendFormat("&f={0}", endDate.Year);
    request.AppendFormat("&g={0}", "d"); //daily

    return request.ToString();
}
```

The code above will go through each data instance in the CSV file, so you just need to save the data instances to arrays. Calculating the return should be straight forward from then on.

```
// Create your data lists
List<DateTime> date = new List<DateTime>();
List<Double> open = new List<Double>();
List<Double> high = new List<Double>();
List<Double> low = new List<Double>();
List<Double> close = new List<Double>();
List<Double> volume = new List<Double>();
List<Double> adjClose = new List<Double>();

//
// ...
//

// inside the DownloadDataFromWeb function:

// Add the data points as you're going through the loop
date.Add(DateTime.Parse(sa[0].Trim('"')));
open.Add(double.Parse(sa[1]));
high.Add(double.Parse(sa[2]));
low.Add(double.Parse(sa[3]));
close.Add(double.Parse(sa[4]));
volume.Add(double.Parse(sa[5]));
adjClose.Add(double.Parse(sa[6]));

//
// ...
//

// Calculate the return after you've downloaded all the data...
```

I hope that's helpful :).

Comment: do you know if there are any publishing restrictions to this data?

Comment: @cfarm54, what do you mean by "publishing restrictions"?

Comment: does yahoo have legal restrictions on how you publish the data? also, in your while loop, would you mind explaining how you are saving the data?

Comment: @cfarm, I don't think Yahoo has any restrictions on what you do with the data, but don't quote me on it :). If you're not using it for commercial purposes, i.e. not selling the data, then I don't think you'll have a problem. I'll update my answer regarding the while loop.

Comment: @Lirik yeah that would be nice. what I'm ultimately trying to do is pull down historical data for any stock, then calculate the daily returns and push those returns to an array. Any clue on how I would be able to implement this using your code?

Comment: @cfarm54, yep, you can pull down the historical data for any stock on Yahoo (end of day data), it's part of my first post on EOD data. Calculating the returns and pushing them to an array should be easy after that (I'll update again).

Comment: @Lirik thanks. is it the same for pulling down index data? e.g. S&P500, NASDAQ, DOW

Comment: @cfarm54, yep, it's the same... you just have to get the right symbol: NASDAQ is ^IXIC, S&P500 is ^GSPC, DOW is ^DJI, etc...

Comment: @Lirik thanks. do you know how to make these requests using silverlight?

Comment: @cfarm54, not sure about silverlight... I've never used it, but I would assume that the same code should work (silverlight is another framework that uses C#, right?). If not, just look up the basic web request and duplicate the logic.

Comment: @Lirik yeah it's not the same because you need to make asynchronous requests. I've never worked with those before have you?

Comment: @cfarm54, I've work with asynchronous requests, but never in the context of Silverlight... I imagine it should be pretty straight forward, take a look at this [Silverlight WebRequest Example](http://tiny.cc/5ppxu) and work my logic into the response.

Comment: This code **does not compile**.  `_sync` is not defined

Comment: Why the need for _concurrency lock_ in the first example?

Answer (score 1):

I agree that you can simply parse the data downloaded from Yahoo/Google or similar sites. If you only interested in daily (eod) data, you may download and use data from this [historical data provider](http://www.kibot.com/) in your application for free. Documentation and ready-to-use C# and VB.NET examples are available.

Answer (score 0):

Even the questions are not .NET classes, you should simply parse the data and use it with .NET:

- [Where can I get free real-time stock data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281263/where-can-i-get-free-real-time-stock-data)?
- [What data source could I use for my stock market program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728126/what-data-source-could-i-use-for-my-stock-market-program)
- [Getting technical data through API’s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926880/getting-technical-data-through-apis)
- [Display stocks data from Google Finance or Yahoo! Finance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395291/display-stocks-data-from-google-finance-or-yahoo-finance)
- [Stock Trading script/language for .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222357/stock-trading-script-language-for-net)
- [Programming a Stock-Trading Application [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614826/programming-a-stock-trading-application)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Mergent Historical Securities Data API at http://www.mergent.com/servius

Answer (score 0):

As a software developer, I would recommend [Alpha Vantage](https://www.alphavantage.co/). They offer realtime and historical stock quotes (daily, weekly, monthly, etc.) as **RESTful JSON APIs**.

It’s completely free with unlimited API calls. It’s realtime as long as the stock is listed on major stock exchanges.

[Here](https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED&symbol=MSFT&apikey=demo) is an example API call for the MSFT daily prices and volumes, enriched with split/dividend adjustments. The latest data point is the realtime information for the current trading day.

They also offer technical analysis APIs on top of the market data according to their documentation.